# Spring boot Multiples bases de datos

Tags: spring-boot

Soy nuevo en `spring boot` y me salte mucho del aprendizaje en `java`.  Con mucho trabajo construí un `webservice / websocket` que trabaja bastante bien.

También dispongo de una `app móvil` que se comunica con el `webservice`. Y estoy trabajando en una `aplicación web` en `Scriptcase` (lo escogí por ser muy sencillo).

Ahora necesito que todo, trabaje **multi base de datos** (con **Mysql**).

Hay una base de datos que contiene todos los usuarios e incluye la/s base/s de datos de trabajo a la/s que puede acceder (relación de 1 a muchos).

Las bases de datos de trabajo son todas iguales (las mismas tablas con diferente información).  Si tengo la necesidad, puedo crear otra base de datos e incluir la información en la base de datos de usuarios que tiene la configuración.

Mi pregunta es como hago para replicar esto en el `webservice` y que cada vez que un usuario se logue, consuma la base de datos que a seleccionado o que tiene permisos.

Si cuentan con un ejemplo sería realmente valioso.

Comment: Como no estas publicando nada de código que muestre que has intentado algo es muy probable que tu pregunta termine siendo cerrada. Ahora bien, te falta explicar más el problema. ¿el usuario elige su base de datos? ¿que elige exactamente, un nombre, una URL? ¿el tiene datos de conexión? ¿como esta el caso de uso que estas planteando?

Comment: Primero seria de de entender tú caso de uso, porque cuando hablas de `múltiples base de datos` que tanto quieres escalar serán 2, 3 o 10 o será una por cliente registrado que podrían ser 1000, y también la forma en que consultas si es con persistencia o con jdbc.

Comment: Voy a intentar explicar mi necesidad:

Comment: Voy a intentar explicar mi necesidad: Pienso tener una base de datos (acceso) con una sola tabla (usuario). Esta tabla tendrá todos los usuarios de la plataforma con la ventaja de identificar la BD a la cual tiene acceso. Estos usuarios inician a través de un app móvil y la idea es que interactúen con la BD que apunta la tabla "usuario".  Recuerden que el desarrollo en spring es un webservice.  Si no fui claro, les agradezco me consulten.

Comment: Para ampliar sobre lo dicho. Imaginen que a parte de la base de datos "acceso" tengo 3 mas que tienen las mismas estructuras y guardan los datos de todos los usuarios con 15 tablas idénticas en estructura.

Comment: El principal problema que veo es que tendrías que tener una conexión jdbc por cada base de datos, podrías crearlas como beans y luego crear 2 servicios uno que retorne la conexión correcta según el la base del cliente y a los servicios de consulta pasar esa conexión como parámetro para ejecutar las consulta a la base de datos, tendrías que elegir jdbcTemplate en vez de JPA porque JPA no es muy flexible para estos casos, lo otro es que utilices una sola base de datos y tus consultas filtren por usuario o empresa a la hora de extraer y modificar datos y no duplicar todas la tablas.